# Eclipse Egit Not Detecting Changed Files

Tags: eclipse, egit

I have been using Egit and Eclipse together for well over a year.  I recently upgraded my computer and had to reinstall everything.  Previously whenever I would make a change to a file  it would immediately get picked up by Egit and show with the red highlight and star next to the file name in the project explorer.

I have everything back up and running exactly as it was, however whenever I make a change the change is not picked up by Egit.  I have to perform a 'git status' in order for the files to show as ready to be staged in the file explorer.  Am I doing something wrong to have Egit automatically detect changed files and has anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- which version of EGit are you using
- do you get the egit team menu if you right-click any resource in your git tracked project ?
- if not then you need to do "Team > Share > Git", then check "Use or create repository in
  parent folder of project". If you are using a very recent nightly build version this
  will be checked automatically.
- when you modify a file tracked by (e)git a text decorator ">" should 
  appear in front of the modified file
- as soon as you stage the modified file (Team > Add) the decorator should show the star
- also the staging view should always show the git status for all modified files

Comment: Thanks, @Matthias. A computer crash appeared to have caused Git to stop tracking a project of mine in Eclipse. Your simple procedure fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to "Add to index" all files again probably

> **Track Changes** 
>  Click **Team** > **Add** on the project node. (This menu item
> may read **Add to Index** on recent versions of Egit)

(From the [EGit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Track_Changes) docs:)

Answer (score 3):

What I've found is that you need to make sure that your git repositories are showing up in the Eclipse `Git Repositories` view.

1. In the repositories view, you click on the [very] little Git icon with a green + (plus) sign to `Add and Existing Local Git Repository`.
2. Browse to the directory that already has a `.git` subdir and click `Finish`.  You should then see you local repo show up in that list.
3. Then you can right click on the repo while still in the repositories view and add pull down to  `Import Projects`.
4. "Import existing projects" is selected. Click Next.
5. Your project should be checked off. Add it to a working set if necessary. Click Next (maybe Finish).

Comment: removing my existing project, and following above to import the project again using above steps did the trick for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For me I have clicked Team --> Advanced --> No Assume Unchanged, fixed the issue

Comment: I agree - this also worked for me. As a side note, this is not strictly just an Eclipse issue. Git didn't see these files as modified, either ("git status" didn't show them as modified)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where all my changes just disappeared.  Somehow, Eclipse had unselected my Git repository.  Once I selected it again, they all came back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added your files to Stage then change the branch it will ask you to commit/stash/reset

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. From your git repository view: **Right-click  -> Show in git staging**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using eclipse version 2021.12. Whenever I made changes on file, the eclipse didn't detect it.

I solve it by using Intelij IDE.

Answer (score 0):

i just faced this problem by now, and i resolved by clicking in button **Refresh** in **Git Staging**:
[image]